# QGIS 3.19 Development version installment

Tags: qgis, windows

I'm trying to install the qgis development version 3.19, as I need it to load a map from Maptiler.
While trying to install I keep getting the same error: [image]

I do get the 3.19 on my device, but when opening i get this error:
[image]

----------------------------------------

Does anyone know how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have qgis_app.dll on your computer? You can see this website about similar issue https://github.com/conda-forge/qgis-feedstock/issues/43
If qgis_app.dll is absent on your computer, try to download this file from third-party site and copy it to your QGIS folder. For example, from here https://www.dll-files.com/qgis_app.dll.html

Comment: I doubt that the service you mention has a fairly recent version of qgis-app.dll.

Comment: Never ever download dll files from random websites. You are highly likely to get malware. Just don't. Ever.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is known and [already has a ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/667).

I suggest to downgrade proj from 8.1 to 8.0 (which should solve your first error message), or use the ["testing" branch](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/testing/osgeo4w-setup.exe) as described in the ticket.
The testing branch will not work on Windows 7.